# set variable only if its name is already interned

Tags: variables

Is there a built-in function/macro of Emacs that sets a variable only if it is already defined?

I mean something like that:

```el
(cl-defmacro set-if-interned (symbol-name value &optional (use-obarray obarray))
  "Set VALUE of symbol with SYMBOL-NAME if it is defined in USE-OBARRAY."
  (declare (debug (form form &optional form)))
  (let ((sym (make-symbol "sym")))
    `(let ((,sym (intern-soft ,symbol-name ,use-obarray)))
       (when ,sym
         (set ,sym ,value)))))
```

Comment: `(when (boundp ,sym)` rather than `(when ,sym` surely?  But then am I missing something if I suggest using a symbol argument and `boundp` in the first place, rather than the dance you're currently performing?

Comment: @phils The symbol should only be set when it is already interned. For an instance it should not be set (and not be interned) by the macro after `(unintern symbol-name obarray)`. And this should obviously not cause an error. Therefore, the construction with `intern-soft`. And in that case `(when ,sym` is just right. It could be extended with `(when (and ,sym (boundp ,sym)) ...)`.

Comment: Right you are; `(boundp nil)` is of course `t`, so your latter version looks right.  The point I was *attempting* (badly) to make was that without `boundp` you're *not* testing whether a variable is set, but rather whether a symbol (which may or may not be bound as a variable) exists in the obarray.

Comment: Regarding the latter part of my initial comment, I guess I don't understand why you're so anxious to avoid interning symbols.

Comment: By eyeball your code looks correct to me. But the macro name should reflect being interned, not being bound, since that's what the behavior is.

Comment: @Drew You are right! That was a bit of a fast shoot. Thx. But nothing predefined you know of, I suppose? I hate to clutter up the obarray if I do not need the symbol in the end. I know that in most cases one can avoid such a construct via `featurep` or `PACKAGE-version`, but sometimes `set-if-interned` is the most appropriate way. E.g., with packages not having `PACKAGE-version`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know of a predefined function/macro that does what you want. Hopefully someone will be able to offer a definitive answer about whether there is one.